# Testing for a PO Box in all of its forms

Tags: c#, regex, validation

We have an C# ASP.Net page where a customer enters in an address where a post office is disallowed as we use UPS for shipping these items. Customers are creative people and they come up with creative means of marking a P.O. Box.

We have this RegEx pattern and it mostly does what we need.

```
(?i)\b[p]*(?:ost)*\.*\s*[o0]*(?:ffice)*\.*\s+?([b]*[o0]*[x])
```

This pattern works in almost every case we have on file:

```
P.O. box 17432
poSt oFFice box 11111
box 222
p0 box 222
#343 po box 
#po box 343
```

It doesn't match (which is the correct behavior):

```
1234 Main St (Shouldn't match, but we have it in there for a negative test case.)
```

However, it also doesn't match these and it should:

```
p0b 222
POB 1112
```

These samples are actually values that users have, in their generous nature, provided us with. ;)

I'm always up for simplification.

Comment: Why would they? Because they're trying to outsmart the system. When the validator is tripped it says "No P.O. boxes" in large, red letters. For the record, we remind the customer frequently that PO boxes aren't allowed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this should be close to what you are looking for:

```
(?i)\b(?:p(?:ost)?\.?\s*[o0](?:ffice)?\.?\s*b(?:[o0]x)?|b[o0]x)
```

The explanation:

```
(?:              # start non-capturing group
    p            # match a 'p'
    (?:ost)?     # optionally match 'ost'
    \.?          # optionally match a '.'
    \s*          # match some number of spaces
    [o0]         # match an 'o' or '0'
    (?:ffice)?   # optionally match 'ffice'
    \.?          # optionally match a '.'
    \s*          # match some number of spaces
    b(?:[o0]x)?  # match 'b', 'box', or 'b0x'
  |              # or
    b[o0]x       # match 'box' or 'b0x'
)
```

Comment: Apparently this regex gets false positives for addresses like 'PSC 001 Box 001' which seems to be a military address.

Comment: I found a slight exception to this that effected our system, people who use "POST BOX", for us this slight fix to the regex captured what we needed `(?i)\b(?:p(?:ost)?\.?\s*(?:[o0](?:ffice)?)?\.?\s*b(?:[o0]x)?|b[o0]x)`(here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/5XNdOM/2))