# RegEx to disallow both P.O. Box and RR in street address textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a Regular Expression Validator control which validates a street address Text Box control.

So far, I have a RegEx which successfully produces an error message from the control for all the common forms of P.O. Box.

```
^(?i)(?!.*P\.? ?O\.? ?Box)[-a-z\d .,/]*$
```

I would also like to disallow '**RR**' and '**Rural Route**'.

For what it's worth, here are a couple of references I have been using while attempting to re-write this RegEx:

**P.O. Box RegEx:** [Testing for a PO Box in all of its forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263956/testing-for-a-po-box-in-all-of-its-forms)

**Rural Route RegEx:** 
[C#: Determing if string is like this pattern; possible regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337820/c-determing-if-string-is-like-this-pattern-possible-regex)

Comment: I don't think that's as complete as you think.  I normally just put "box 123" I don't write the "po" part.

Comment: I've also seen usages of "Postal Bag 123" and "Bag 123", and a few other variants instead of "PO Box 123" or "Box 123".

Comment: Oh, and what happens if the address is in Box Hill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but I don't see any point of regex. Do something like this and you can exclude multiple words in any part of a string instead.

```
IEnumerable<string> disallow =  new String[] { "RR", "Rural Route", "Box"};
bool invalidAddress = false;

string address = "1728 Box 12".ToLower();

foreach (var item in disallow)
{
    if (address.Contains(item.ToLower()))
        invalidAddress = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this code sample. At the time, I was really trying to use a RegEx but I don't think I was able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Is it worth writing a custom validator that just checked for strings containing a few options such as "PO", "P.O.", "RR", "Rural Route".

Regex is a very powerful tool but not easy to maintain. If you can write code that's easier to understand, even if it takes longer, that's almost always a win in the longer term.

Lastly, I'm not sure what you're looking for is even totally possible in regex. You can choose to not have a valid capture for some of the text but since the rest of the text will have a valid capture the validator might still pass.